# Google Spreadsheet (Using named range in script)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Trying to get my script to use a named range.
In that range I am trying to reset the cell colors back to white.
I keep getting an object error, can't figure out how to make this work.

```js
function resetCheckDirectory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tableRange = ss.getRangeByName("rangename");
  tableRange.setBackgrounds("#FFF");
};
```

Comment: So, your variable `tableRange` is being set to `null`?  Run the code with the [debugger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/troubleshooting#using_the_debugger_and_breakpoints).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a simple spelling error, `setBackground` in this case is without `s` because you are setting a **single color** to multiple cells (the argument is "#FFF")

So the code is :

```
function resetCheckDirectory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tableRange = ss.getRangeByName("NamedRange1");
  tableRange.setBackground("#FFF");
};
```

to summarize :

- `setBackground` is used with single string argument and applies to single cell or any range where all colors are identical
- `setBackgrounds` is used with a 2 dimensions array as argument and applies to a range where you need to set different colors in different cells.

Comment: I swear, that normally troubleshooting is my thing. Right now; feel like I don't even deserve Google spreadsheets, with how trivial my 2 problems were. Thanks again serge, up votes are coming you way once a reach their 15 reputation requirement.